# application id is not associated with package while signing in google play?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

As title says, I encounter this problem. Documentation says to do this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.APP_ID"
android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

I had done and my app_id is 12 digits. Other people getting this similar error was their app_id s were more than 12 digits. But mine is 12. However, it does not work, I cant sign in. Error also says check your manifest. I have checked and it is the same as above. Why is application id ,which i got it from google play console, not associated with my package name? Do i have to do something with sha1 key? (I am now in th alpha test)

Regards

Answer (score 5):

I also received this error and fixed it by adding one of my tester accounts to the Google Play Services list of testers for the app.

The account I had on the tablet was not in the list of permitted tester accounts in the Google Play Console.

Once I had done this, I was able to connect with no issues.

For reference my app_id entry looks like this :-

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

you must also check that users gmail id is added in testing or not ?
if not then add it to Play **Console** -> **Game Services** -> **Testing**

Comment: Can confirm I got the "not associated with package" log error and adding a testing email account fixed it.  Another example of a bad error message.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an extra `.appstate` in the `android:name` for the `APP_ID`.  Mine looks like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
                android:value="@string/gplus_id" />
```

Also, make certain that you don't have another string called `app_id` or it may get confused.  This is why I called mine `gplus_id`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by deleting

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

from AndroidManifest.xml.